# how do I get my applet to talk to the page?

Tags: java, ajax, applet

I'm not having any luck finding info on how I can get my applet to talk to the page that it's embedded in.  The thing I'm after, specifically, is to incorporate an applet into an AJAX process and have various events in the applet control whether the AJAX request can be made, as well as adding a few params to it. 
Is this possible? If so, what's the methodology behind it?

TIA,
Dr.D

Comment: Look at https://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/

Comment: This is a great answer... Please repeat it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: liveconnect is not supported fully on all browsers, especially on the mac. However, you can use a subset which is. I tested several browsers for their liveconnect support, the results are availble in a blog post: [applets: missing information about liveconnect and deployment](http://blog.aarhusworks.com/applets-missing-information-about-liveconnect-and-deployment/)